# Algorithm to identify periodic signal spikes

Tags: filters, algorithms

I'm working with a special chip that allows me to record current draw on phones. This chip logs data with its internal timestamps.

I now need to generate a unique signal that will allow me to map the chip's timestamps with the phone's. Given how phone components are usually complex with low-power states, I've decided to use the flashlight to generate this signal.

Assuming I can rapidly turn on and turn off the flashlight over a period of *n* seconds, this will generate corresponding spikes in current draw.

What signal processing algorithms can I use to later identify the start/end of this flashlight (current-draw) pattern?